# Page not updating in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating a web app, where I have one page which is home.html and about.html. In the home.html I have list of users, and when they click on one of the users, it goes to about.html, but does not show the users info. Can anyone check my code, to see what I have done wrong. Thanks in advance.

> Here is my code. (home.html)

```
    <form name="myForm">

<label>Search
<input type="text" size="35" ng-model="userSearch">
</label>

</form>

<br/>

<label>Filters</label>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-link">+ Add Filter</button>
<hr>
<legend>Users</legend>




<div class="people" ng-repeat="person in userInfo.lawyers | filter:userSearch" >



    <a href="#/lawyer/{{ person.id }}">
    <img ng-src="{{person.imgUrl}}"/>
    <span class="name">{{person.firstName}} </span>
    <span class="name">{{person.lastName}} </span>

   <p class="title">{{person.title}} </p>
  <span class="date">{{person.date}} </span>


</a>


</div>
```

> About.html

```
<div class="people-view">
  <h2 class="name">{{person.first}}</h2>
    <h2 class="name">{{person.last}}</h2>

  <span class="title">{{person.title}}</span>

  <span class="date">{{person.date}} </span>



</div>




<div class="list-view">


  <form>
    <fieldset ng-disabled="inactive">

  <legend>Basic Info</legend>

  <b>First Name:</b>
  <input type="text" ng-model="person.first">
  <br>
  <b>Last Name:</b>
  <input type="text" ng-model="person.last">
  <br>
  <b>Email:</b>
  <input type="email" ng-model="person.email">
  <br>
  <b>Phone:</b>
  <input type="num"  ng-model="person.phone">
  <br>
  <b>Website:</b>
  <input type="text" ng-model="person.website">
  <br>
  <b>Education:</b>
  <input type="text" ng-model="person.education">
  <br>
  <b>Education Year:</b>
  <input type="text" ng-model="person.year">

  <br>




  </form>



</div>
</div>
```

> App.js

```
var app = angular.module("Portal", ['ngRoute',  'ui.bootstrap' ]);



    app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {

        //form setting to true
        $scope.inactive = true;

        $scope.confirmedAction = function() {

        isConfirmed.splice($scope.person.id, 1);

        location.href = '#/lawyer';


    }

});





app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/lawyer", {
        controller: "HomeController",
        templateUrl: "partials/home.html"
    })
    .when("/lawyer/:id", {
        controller: "LawyerController",
        templateUrl: "partials/about.html"
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/lawyer'

    });

});
```

> Controller

```
app.controller('LawyerController', ['$scope', 'people', '$routeParams',
    function ($scope, people, $routeParams) {

        people.getUserInfo().then(function (response) {

            $scope.person = people.getUserInfo();

            console.log($scope.person.lawyers);
        }, function (error) {
            console.log(error)
        });
    }]);
```

> HomeController

```
var isConfirmed = false;
app.controller('HomeController', function($scope, people, $http) {
    if (!isConfirmed) {
        people.getUserInfo().then(function (response) {
            $scope.userInfo = response.data;

            isConfirmed = $scope.userInfo;
            console.log($scope.userInfo.lawyers);
        }, function (error) {
            console.log(error)
        });
    }
});
```

> Services

```
    app.factory('people', ['$http', function($http) {
    var userInfo = {  
        getUserInfo: function () {
            return $http.get('https://******************');

        }
    };
    return userInfo;
}]);
```

Comment: You need to share your controller codes to see how you manage to pass data from home to about page

Comment: @EmadDehnavi check updated question

Comment: where is the code for `LawyerController`?  you only show one controller here, `MyCtrl`, and it isn't even used in either of these routes.  The `LawyerController` is the only one that would have any impact on the question you have asked, and thus the most important one to show here.

Comment: see updated question @Claies

Comment: That is only app.js, I need your HomeController, LawyerController , because then I can see how you get data for userInfo.lawyers

Comment: @EmadDehnavi see updated question

Comment: ok, so you are passing an `id` to your `LawyerController`, but you don't appear to be using it.  also, you are calling a `people.getUserInfo()` function that you haven't listed, so it continues to be unclear what data you have here vs what you expect to have.  plus, this code makes no sense; you call an async function, and in the `then`, you try to assign your property to another call to the same function?

Comment: @Claies check now

Comment: how are you expecting this to return **one** user, when you only have one method, which *appears* to return the whole list?

Comment: the more code you post, the less it looks like you are even trying to do what your question asks about.

Comment: @Claies can we do a chat?

Comment: what I want to achieve is when they click on user 1 it should shows the user 1 info in about.html.

Comment: I really can't explain to you how to write a controller from scratch to do what you want to do from my mobile device......

Comment: @EmadDehnavi any solutions?

Comment: @Claies so, how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others mentioned, your whole code is in wrong way! but I will try to help as much as I can.

You don't have any method in LawyerController to get the data, so let's begin from that :

change your  $routeProvider in app.js like this to have a method :

```
$routeProvider
   .when("/lawyer", {
       controller: "HomeController",
       templateUrl: "partials/home.html"
    })
    .when("/lawyer/:id", {
    controller: "LawyerController",
    templateUrl: "partials/about.html",
    method: 'lawyerInit'
   })
   .otherwise({
       redirectTo: '/lawyer'

   });
```

Then change your `LawyerController` to something like this :

```
app.controller('LawyerController', ['$scope', 'people', '$routeParams',
   function ($scope, people, $routeParams) {

     $scope.lawyerInit = function(){
          people.getUserInfo().then(function (response) {

        $scope.getAll= people.getUserInfo();
        for (var i=0; i<=$scope.getAll.length -1; i++){
              if($scope.getAll[i].lawyers.id==$routeParams.id){
                   $scope.person= $scope.getAll[i];
               }
           }
        console.log($scope.person.lawyers);
    }, function (error) {
        console.log(error)
    });
     }


}]);
```

Hope this work, I was not sure how is your json response, if you get error in this line `if($scope.getAll[i].lawyers.id==$routeParams.id)` you need make sure the `id` where is exactlly in your json object.

Comment: well, the about.html page is showing empty fields, when click on "User 1". Also, I am not grabbing it from the json, its grabbing it from a backend api.

Comment: Yes but the respnse from api usually is it a json for the most part. can u show me whatever u see in console .log when you run this console.log($scope.userInfo); in your home controller

Comment: it just shows this: Object {data: null, status: -1, config: Object, statusText: "", headers: function}

Comment: if you want, we can chat?

Comment: That mean you are not geeting the data from your api.

Comment: because I think it is going on in the about.html

Comment: {data: null, status: -1, config: Object, statusText: "", headers: function} This mean you not get anything from your backend , I can't help u if you not show me the response object you get from backend